# show a page inside a document ready

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to show a page with ajax inside a div but it does not work it dost not show me anything here is my codes

> HTML

```
  <div class="cols ">

    <div id="show">


    </div>
    </div>
```

> AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){

      $.ajax({
          url:"../../control/operation/type.php",
          typ

e:"POST",
          success:function(data)
          {

            $('#show').html(data);
          } 

        });



      });
    </script>
```

> type.php page

```
    $get = $data->show(" SELECT * FROM movies  ");
foreach ($get as $row) {
 $id=$row['m_id'];
 $name=$row['m_name'];
 $type=$row['type'];
 $description=$row['description'];
 $trailer=$row['trailer'];
 $img=$row['img'];
     ?>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-2 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="viewmovie.php?movie=<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <div class="front" style="background-image: url(../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>)" >

            <div class="inner">
            <h5><?php echo "$name"; ?></h5>
              <h6>خوله‌ک  <?php echo "$time";  ?> </h6>
              <p></p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="inner">

              <p ><?php echo $description ?></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

it give me alert when i put it in but it does not show me anything else i even tried to load only `h1` tag still did not work can any one help me with this

Comment: did you have any value inside `data` ? can you check and see onces

Comment: @Swati no i dont have any data i just want to select all i tried to include a data as well but still did not get any result ive tried with button click as well

Comment: You need to return all the html code you're producing in your PHP file back to your ajax call, so that `data` will get it and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo` all your html code back to your ajax call:

```
<?php
$get = $data->show(" SELECT * FROM movies  ");
$result = "";
foreach ($get as $row)
{
    $id = $row['m_id'];
    $name = $row['m_name'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $trailer = $row['trailer'];
    $img = $row['img'];

    $result .= '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-2 col-6"';
    $result .= ' ontouchstart=';
    $result .= '"this.classList.toggle';
    $result .= "('hover');";
    $result .= '">';
    $result .= '<div class="container">';
    $result .= '<a href="viewmovie.php?movie=' . $id . '>';
    $result .= '<div class="front" style="background-image: url(../../src/upload/posts/' . $img . ')">';
    $result .= '<div class="inner">';
    $result .= '<h5>' . $name . '</h5>';
    $result .= '<h6>خوله‌ک  ' . $time . '</h6>';
    $result .= '<p></p>';
    $result .= '</div></div><div class="back"><div class="inner"><p >' . $description . '</p></div></div></a></div></div>';
}
return $result;

?>
```

Comment: i tried that now but did not got any result i checked my console log i did not have errors as well

Comment: Try to return something before the loop, like `return '<p>Test</p>';`, to see if it works.

Comment: it does not work it do not return anything like i mentioned i even tried normal php tag just to see if it works or not i do not get any result sure i included the libirayes i done other works with it but this one i dont mange to do it

Comment: @mhamadaras then there is something wrong with your path in your ajax call `../../control/operation/type.php`. What response are you getting? 404? 500?

Comment: i did not notice u edit the post i tried that and it worked thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not mentioning the post update.